# How can I use latex code in R plot?

Tags: r, plot, latex, label

is there a way to use Latex code in a plot? I have got two vectors, for example a,b. I want to create something like this:

`graph <- rbind(a, b)`

```
colnames(pokus) = names(a)

barplot(pokus, beside = TRUE)
```

but I would like to change the "colnames(pokus)", so that the inequality would look like in Latex - I have to use it in latex later and it should look good... I hope there is an easy solution but it´s my first time that I´m working with R...

Comment: See examples in `plotmath`.

Comment: also see the `tikzDevice` package (which may be archived/slightly harder to get) and in particular the stuff in the `knitr` website/documentation about using it.

Comment: I tried plotmath, I can put it in the label but not into the tickmarks. Is there a way how to do it? I need the tickmarks look like `0 \leq N \leq 10`...